# can i restrict the edittext widget to accept phone numbers only?

Tags: android, phone-number, android-edittext

Does the EditText widget phone numbers from simple numbers? for example, edittext has a input method as password, which specifies that whatever typed in is a password. 
Also we can restrict it to enter only numbers, but i want to tackle with phone numbers.

Comment: Yes you can. Choose the xml file and go to Eclip's design view. There is a option available when u select the EditText field. sry i'm from office and Eclipse and android SDK not available here.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 6):

Yes sure you can use android:phoneNumber="true"

Answer (score 2):

[Please see this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-edittext-inputtype/) .